# String type to Object

Tags: .net, vb.net

sorry for a noob question but don't want to repeat this "MainFrm1.UcSettings" thing everytime..

```
MainFrm1.UcSettings.IDtxt.text = 0112
MainFrm1.UcSettings.Nametxt.text = "Chuck Norris"
and so on...
```

what i want it to do is to set a string like this..

```
Dim str as string = "MainFrm1.UcSettings"
dim obj as object = str

obj.IDtxt.text = 0112
obj.Nametxt.text = "Chuck Norris"
and so on...
```

but what i've done is wrong..lol how to do this in correct way ? tnx in advance..

Comment: What ever the type of `UcSettings` use that and store in temp variable, in your case it is 1st line of 2nd code blocks and use that. If you can tell me what is type of `UcSettings`, then I can post answer for this.

Comment: hmmmm..so im just near from perfection eh ?

Comment: The way you can written needs reflection to achieve this, but there is a simple way, that I've described.If you can tell me what is type of `UcSettings`, then I can post answer for this.

Comment: it's a usercontrol sir..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm expecting your UcSettings to be a custom user control. Then you can use it is a type:

```
Dim uc as UcSettings = MainFrm1.UcSettings

uc.IDtxt.text = 0112
uc.Nametxt.text = "Chuck Norris"
```

Comment: u sir just nailed it ! tnx :D